# How can you make a function generic over whether its args are borrowed mutably or not?

Tags: rust

For something trivial like:

```
fn do_nothing(x: &i64) -> &i64 {
  x
}

fn do_nothing(x: &mut i64) -> &mut i64 {
  x
}
```

You could make this generic for some type T but then you have to dance around the generic type. Is there any way to just have the `mut` inferred depending on the argument passed?

Comment: Could you clarify your question? The title talks about generic structs but there are no structs in your example?

Comment: If you're willing to use [unstable features](https://blog.rust-lang.org/inside-rust/2023/02/23/keyword-generics-progress-report-feb-2023.html)…

Comment: @Frxstrem sorry, original example used a struct but I figured demonstrating with a fn is the same and easier to get the point across. Fixed the title.

Comment: @Caesar That article looks to be about `const` and `async` functions, not about the mutability of a reference (`&` vs `&mut`). Does that proposal also support mutability generics?

Comment: Ah, apologies, I mixed up compile-time `const`ness and `mut`.

Comment: What's wrong with `fn do_nothing<T>(x: T) -> T { x }`? Also both of your functions have borrowed args.

Comment: @drewtato I mistakenly deleted the word `mutably` from `mutably borrowed or not`. And generics are heavy handed if I know that `T` is a specific type.

Comment: Are you doing anything mutable in the mut version? If not, maybe just `AsRef<i64>` is fine?

Answer (score 1):

You can by using your own trait:

```
trait MaybeMutRef {}

impl<T: ?Sized> MaybeMutRef for &T {}
impl<T: ?Sized> MaybeMutRef for &mut T {}

fn do_nothing<T: MaybeMutRef>(x: T) -> T {
    x
}
```

The value of this trait by itself isn't that useful.  If you need to alter behavior based on mutability, you can do that by adding some members to the trait.

```
trait MaybeMutRef {
    type Target: ?Sized;
    
    fn get(&self) -> &Self::Target;
    fn get_mut(&mut self) -> Option<&mut Self::Target>;
}

impl<T: ?Sized> MaybeMutRef for &T {
    type Target = T;
    
    fn get(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        self
    }
    
    fn get_mut(&mut self) -> Option<&mut Self::Target> {
        None
    }
}

impl<T: ?Sized> MaybeMutRef for &mut T {
    type Target = T;
    
    fn get(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        self
    }
    
    fn get_mut(&mut self) -> Option<&mut Self::Target> {
        Some(self)
    }
}

fn do_nothing<T: MaybeMutRef>(mut x: T) {
    if let Some(x) = x.get_mut() {
        // Mutable reference, x is a &mut T::Target
    } else {
        let x = x.get();
        // Immutable reference, x is a &T::Target
    }
}
```

The compiler should be able to inline the `get*` calls and therefore eliminate the dead branches for you.

Note that this is a bit of a weird pattern, and I would be careful about using it all over the place.  However, this approach could be useful if you have an algorithm where the logic is almost the same for both the immutable and mutable cases except for one or two details that you can make conditional on the argument's mutability.

If the reference needs to be pointing to a specific type of referent, you can use generic constraints as usual:

```
fn do_nothing<T: MaybeMutRef<Target=i64>>(mut x: T) { todo!() }
```

As a final word of advice, I don't think this is the kind of function signature you want to expose in your API.  Instead, consider making the trait and function a private detail and having more Rust-y public functions, like this:

```
fn do_nothing_impl<T: MaybeMutRef<Target=i64>>(mut x: T) { todo!() }

pub fn do_nothing(x: &i64) { do_nothing_impl(x); }
pub fn do_nothing_mut(x: &mut i64) { do_nothing_impl(x); }
```